# I don't understand incompatible type error in assignment

Tags: flowtype

Can someone explain why I have the flow error

```
object type (This type is incompatible with object type Indexable signature is incompatible:)
```

for the assignment in the last line of

```
const plain: { [key: string]: string } = { prop: '' };
type TestType = { [key: string]: string | number };
const testVar: TestType = plain;
```

I have no error if I remove the type specification for plain...

Many thanks !

Comment: Seems like Flow is unable to see that one is a subset of the other, one being `string`and the other one `string | number`. It would be fine as simple type but the key/value hash map type used here is a special construct. Just one more limitation - check the Github "issues" section for Flow, people discover five new limitations every single day (none of them are addressed and remain open issue forever). Feel free to add your issue to that growing list. _I actually use Flow myself, I just accept that the tool is severely limited in what it can do._ **I'd declare `plain` as type `TestType` too!**

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have filed an issue (https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5458) as you suggested. If you write your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir Kurchatkin answered to this question in the issue I opened on github (https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5458) :

Objects are invariant by default. You can make it covariant like this:

```
const plain: { [key: string]: string } = { prop: '' };
type TestType = { +[key: string]: string | number };
const testVar: TestType = plain;
```